# Not getting any records from ContentVersion in Salesforce SOQ query which we are not owner of

Tags: apex, soql, contentversion, contentdocument

When I am creating a new record (release), I would like to get a file off a related record (inventory) and then create a copy of it on the release.

The problem I am facing, is that this only works if the user owns the file on the inventory.

I have looked into ways around this and apart from assigning the user a 'View all Files' permission I could only find a small number of similar solutions but struggled to make anythign work for me. any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
List<ContentVersion> sourceFiles = [
                    SELECT 
                        Id, 
                        Title,
                        VersionData,
                        PathOnClient,
                        FirstPublishLocationId 
                    FROM 
                        ContentVersion
                    WHERE 
                        FirstPublishLocationId = : invLines
                    AND 
                        (Title LIKE '%TRACE%' OR Title LIKE '%CERT%')
                ];

if (! sourceFiles.isEmpty() ) {
                    for(ContentVersion cdl : sourceFiles){

                        ContentVersion x = new ContentVersion(
                            Title = cdl.Title + ' - ' + lineMapName.get(cdl.FirstPublishLocationId),
                            VersionData = cdl.VersionData,
                            PathOnClient = cdl.PathOnClient,
                            FirstPublishLocationId = lineMap.get(cdl.FirstPublishLocationId)
                        );

                        docsToImport.add(x);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: does the class have `with sharing` or `without sharing` ? N.B the `if (!sourceFiles.isEmpty()` is unnecessary; just let the for loop execute 0 times. less-is-more

Comment: The class has with sharing, You are right. It is unnecessary, I will remove it. Thank you

Comment: is user having the issue set up with `CRM Content User` checked true? This can be enabled gloablly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Managed to find solution to my problem over the weekend and fixed it with a flow.

I fixed my issue by changing away from the Convent Version object.
Instead I got the Content Document Link on the Inventory object and used this to create a new Content document Link and update the Title on the Content Document.
On the new Content Document Link I set the share type and the visibility to all users.

[image]
[image]

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test this. But eh... For the service user's profile... Add access to apexClass: ContentVersion. And access to fieldPermissions: FirstPublishLocationId, VersionData, PathOnClient.